# Issues with ScrollBar and JTable selection

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel, jscrollpane

Issues:

1. Need the scrollbar to increase to the panel height even when maximized.
2. When clicked on 1 or 2, need to change the selection color to some other color.
3. When clicked on 'x', the font should change.

Code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.MatteBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class Sample1 extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Sample1 frame = new Sample1();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Sample1() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(new MatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, (Color) new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);

        Vector str = new Vector<>();
        Vector v = new Vector();
        v.add("1");
        v.add("x");
        Vector v1 = new Vector();
        v1.add("2");
        v1.add("x");
        str.addElement(v);
        str.addElement(v1);
        DefaultTableModel mo = new DefaultTableModel(str,str);
        final JTable list = new JTable(mo);
        list.setBorder(new CompoundBorder());
        list.setBackground(new Color(238, 232, 170));
        list.setShowGrid(false);
//      list.setListData(str);
        list.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(10);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 300));
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        list.setTableHeader(null);
        list.setFillsViewportHeight(true); 
        panel.add(scrollPane);

        final JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setBorder(new MatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, (Color) new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        contentPane.add(panel_1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel_1.setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));

        JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.add(panel_2, "1");

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("First");
        panel_2.add(lblNewLabel);

        JPanel panel_3 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.add(panel_3, "2");

        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Second");
        panel_3.add(lblNewLabel_1);


        list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                int row = list.getSelectedRow();
                int column = list.getSelectedColumn();
                CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) panel_1.getLayout();
                cl.show(panel_1,list.getValueAt(row, column).toString());
            }
        });

//      list.add
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Need the scrollbar to increase to the panel height even when maximized.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
```

This will solve your first problem.